# How to check my progress towards “Tag Badges” in iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app, badge-progress

Where can I trace my progress toward "Tag Badges" and "Privileges" in iOS app of stackexchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS app (and the Android app for that matter) can't show you that information because it isn't offered by the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Use the mobile browser of your device to peek at that data using the website.